# Is there a way to create a list of random strings in code for testing C#?

Tags: c#, random

For testing purposes, I generally have to create a huge array of strings that are all random or unique in code. Is there an easy way to do this in C#...instead of manually instantiating a bunch of strings. If we could use this to also be an array of some custom class with simple properties being initialized, then that would be great.

EDIT: I have tried doing this:

```
string myItems[] = { "ONE", "TWO" , "THREE" etc..}

For( loop through 100 )
{
    Use GetRandomFileName()
}
```

Comment: What do you need, random _or_ unique?

Comment: I tried instantiating it manually: Like string myItems[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" } etc...

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes..Sorry I need unique

Comment: you can add some prefix/suffix with `                        DateTime.Now.GetHashCode().ToString();`

Comment: 3 downvotes for this question?

Comment: @user1202434 As you can clearly see, yes.

Comment: @Adnan thanks for pointing out the obvious. You make people very welcome on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GUID's

Here goes the code for it.
in c#.NET

```
string id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(id);
```

if you want 100's of those just use a loop.

```
int i=0;
List<string> id = null;
while(i<100)
{ 
    id.add(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    i++;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That does seem good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but it's largely based on what you specific requirements are.

### A random string

Here is an example function that will build you a string of a particular `length` out of a-z characters by generating the [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for those characters (97 to 122) and converting them into `char`s before appending them to our string.

```
public string BuildRandomString(Random random, int length)
{
    var random = new Random();
    string text = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        text += (char)random.Next(97, 122);

    return text;
}
```

### A list of 100

We can use this to generate a `List` of 100 random strings like so:

```
var random = new Random();
var strings = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    strings.Add(BuildRandomString(random, 10));
```

### Varying length

This can be extended further to get a varying length string like so:

```
public string BuildRandomString(Random random, int minLength, int maxLength)
{
    var text = string.Empty;
    var length = random.Next(minLength, maxLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        text += (char)random.Next(97, 122);

    return text;
}
```

### Further extension

This method can be extended to give whatever you like, an example improvement could be make sure each generated string has at least one vowel so it looks more like a word.

The [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) will be handy when extending the method to give more ideal results based on your requirements.

### `System.Random`

You will have noticed the `Random` object being instantiated and passed in as an argument to the methods. We can't just instantiate a new one in `BuildRandomString()` because of how 'pseudo-random' numbers work. They take a "seed" which determines what the first number, and second number, etc. is. This has up sides because we can explicitly specify a seed if we want to work on the same 'random' data multiple times by using `new Random(102302)` for example.

When you don't use a seed the [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) is used which generates a seed based on the system clock. The problem is that this number will return the same seed when used in close succession so we need to use the same variable. It could easily be a member variable to the class containing our `BuildRandomString` method also.

From MSDN:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.

Thanks to dialer for pointing it out.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I reckon this won't work because each iteration will use the same seed.

Comment: @leppie and that's why we don't blindly counter-vote. (disclaimer: I didn't downvote).

Comment: @dialer: For something like this there should be enough time for the seed to change. Unit tests could be problematic though.

Comment: @leppie No, there is certainly not enough time. `public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount)`, and `Environment.TickCount` is measured in ms. 10 iterations over that function is faster than 1 ms, even without optimizations. As a side node, instead of passing a `Random` argument, you could use a static field that is initialized the first time the function is used.

Comment: @dialer: What I am saying. In real world it might work. But answerer has edited now to be correct.